# App Store not recognizing app installed from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

When I install my app through Xcode, App Store no longer recognizes that the app is installed. This makes things like deep links difficult to test.

I have verified that my Product Bundle Identifier is the same for Debug and Release (it's different for AdHoc, but that shouldn't matter in this case). When downloading from App Store, it does not add a second app, it simply updates the previous app.

Comment: Had a similar issue some time ago, was resolved by completely uninstalling the app & then reinstalling fresh. It appears that the deep links are setup upon initial install.

Comment: I don't understand why this is an issue for deep links. You can test deep links without having the app available on the appstore. Also, when it updates the previous app instead of creating a new one, this is the expected result actually.

Comment: @Edudjr I should have specified it better - it is a problem with Branch links because you can set them up to link either to the App Store or to the app depending on if the app is installed or not. So even if the app is installed (through Xcode), a branch link will open the App Store because it can't find the app.